# Minimal Ubuntu install for Beaglebone Black

Tags: ubuntu, beagleboneblack

I would like to reduce the overhead required by Ubuntu 13.04 on Beaglebone Black in order to improve the performance of some programs I'm running. What are the easiest ways to reduce the overhead of Ubuntu for the beaglebone black. I use the gpio library for python and run some programs written in C++.

Note: I installed [this 13.04 version](http://www.armhf.com/index.php/boards/beaglebone-black/) on the beaglebone black eMMC using [this method](http://shrkey.com/setting-up-beaglebone-black-to-boot-off-the-microsd-card/).

Answer (score 2):

I used the Debian distro discussed here: http://elinux.org/BeagleBoardDebian#eMMC:_BeagleBone_Black

I found it to be very stripped down and extremely useful. Basically only has the bare components. I realize this is not exactly what you are asking for but Ubunutu was originally based on Debian and will provide many familiar features, such as the apt package manager.